# Find the distribution of a product of LOGNormal distributed variables

Tags: probability

Recall that $Y \sim LOGN(\mu, \sigma^2)$ if $lnY \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Assume that $Y_1 \sim LOGN(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2), i = 1, \dots, n$ are independent.

1. Find the distribution of $\prod\limits_{i=1}^nY_i$
2. Find $\mathbb{E}[\prod\limits_{i=1}^nY_i]$

My first thought was to use the moment generating function. However, I looked it up and it appears that this is not always defined for a lognormal-distribution, so there is probably an easier way. Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $Y_i \sim \exp(N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2))$. What happens when you multiply such random variables? The "terms" in the exponents add up.

Comment: Thank you! However, wouldn't this become a very complex function with an e power raised to an other e power? How exactly would this look like? And do you also have any ideas on 2?

Comment: For example, then $Y_1Y_2 \sim \exp(N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)+N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2))$. We observe that the exponent is another normal random variable (I assume you know that the sum of two normals is normal). In other words, $Y_1Y_2$ is $e^Z$ where $Z$ is normal. This means $\log Y_1Y_2 = Z$, or $Y_1Y_2$ is log-normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! All of a sudden it makes a lot of sense! And you can extend this idea to all the n random variables right? Do you maybe also have an idea on how I should approach question 2? Thanks again for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, the general case uses the same idea. You will have the sum of $n$ normal random variables in the exponent, which again is normal.

Comment: @Lord Soth, Your answer is simply wrong. If the two normal distributions are not supposed to be independent, their sum is generally not normal. For example, if $Z$ is normal, then $-Z$ is also normal but their sum $Z-Z=0$ is not normal and the product of $\exp(Z)\exp(-Z)$ is the constant $1$, which is clearly not lognormal.